# Similarity algorithms

Tags: probability, algorithms, large-data

Let's say I have 300 restaurants that I want to compare to each other on the basis of a "similarity score". To try and determine similarity scores, I pick a reference restaurant and pick 3 other restaurants at random and ask a user "Which of these 3 restaurants is most similar to the reference restaurant?". The user selects one of the 3 restaurants and the data is recorded. How many times does this question have to be answered before I can reasonably start to use the data to determine similarity between restaurants?

Comment: You should expand your question on how you will analyze similarity: Are you using a `tanimoto similarity score`? Euclidean distance? Clustering? Pearson correlation? IMO that needs to be stated in order for us to best answer.

Comment: This question is about conducting a study to measure subjective similarities between a large number of objects, right? Then it is more a psychological/psychometric than a statistical question.

Comment: @cerd - I did not have a specific similarity score in mind. I would like to use a system a) that can be calculated with a small amount of data and b) where the distance between the ranked objects is meaningful (I forget the technical term for that). Could you make a recommendation?

Comment: @ttnphns I assumed it had the characteristics of a statistical question as I want to know the sample size required to make meaningful comparisons.

Comment: @zgall1 - Euclidean distance/Pearson correlation may work well and you can start to calculate those as soon as you start receiving data. You should check out 'Programming Collective Intelligence' - chapter 2 and chapter 3. It's a very practical approach to what I think you are after.

Comment: @cerd Looks like a great resource on first glance. Thank you very much for the suggestion.

Comment: @cerd After looking through resource you suggested, I'm not sure if Euclidean distance/Pearson correlation would work for my intended purpose. In the examples provided in the book, the users are ranking items on a scale, say 1 to 5 and similarity is determined based on comparing ranked items. In my example, I do not have an exact numerical ranking but only a measure saying that of the three items in question  (X, Y, Z), the reference item is most similar to item X (or Y or Z). Is there a way to adapt the formula to suit this situation?